# Disabling multiple buttons with the same class attribute but different ids

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple buttons  with the same class attribute but different ids. I tried disabling them but failed.
     submit 
     submit

```
document.querySelector(".submit").disable = true;
```

Answer (score 4):

While [.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns only the first element you need [.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) in order to disable all buttons with the same class. Instead of **disable** you need to use **disabled** and a loop like [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".submit").forEach(e => e.disabled = true)
```

```html
<button type="button" class="submit">1</button>
<button type="button" class="submit">2</button>
<button type="button" class="submit">3</button>
<button type="button" class="submit">4</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Jquery disable button:

```
$('.submit').attr('disabled',true);
```

or

```
$('.submit').prop("disabled", true);
```

or the old way :

```
var buttons= document.getElementsByClassName("submit");
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].disabled = true;
}
```